Export buttons like PDF, EXCEL Print not showing photo instead shows a blank filed
I'm using Laravel 11 with AdminLTE,
I have a table with four columns, one column is Photo where the Profile of user is displayed.
It works will but when I want to export to a PDF file, the photos are not showing in the PDF file.
the image in my Datatable:

the exported pdf file (photo is not showing):

 $(function() {

const table = $("#example1").DataTable({
"responsive": true,
"lengthChange": false,
"dom": 'Bfrtip',
"autoWidth": false,
"buttons": [{
extend: 'excel',
footer: true,
                },
                {
                    extend: 'pdf',
                    footer: true,
                   
                {
                    extend: 'print',
                    footer: true,
                   
                }
            ]
        });

});
